# javascript - regex - repetitive tags matches syndrome

Tags: javascript, regex

something weird for me when trying to figure out the difference between these two cases

**case 1:**

a match with 2 groups

```
var reg = /@([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*)\)/;
var text = ' @ifblank(1, @ifblank(2, 3) ) ';

text.match(reg);
```

result (as expected)

```
match 1: "ifblank"
match 2: "1, @ifblank(2, 3) "
```

**case 2:**

a match with 3 groups

```
var reg = /@([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*), (.*)\)/;
var text = ' @ifblank(1, @ifblank(2, 3) ) ';

text.match(reg);
```

result (not as expected)

```
match 1: "ifblank"
match 2: "1, @ifblank(2"
match 3: "3) "
```

what I was expecting is:

```
match 1: "ifblank"
match 2: "1"
match 3: "@ifblank(2, 3)"
```

I assume this because of I use the same tags inside one format, but how can I create my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second group, instead of using  `.*` to match *anything*, use `[^,]+` to match anything but a comma:

```
@([a-zA-Z]+)\(([^,]*), (.*)\)
               ^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/uyfoqq/2

If you want, you can also trim off the space at the end of the third group by requiring that the last character matched in it is `\S` (a non-whitespace character):

```
@([a-zA-Z]+)\(([^,]*), (.*\S) *\)
                          ^^ ^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/uyfoqq/3

Answer (score 2):

If you have only digits at the first index, i.e. where you want your

match 2: "1"

then you can change your regular expression to

var reg = /@([a-zA-Z]+)((\d), (.*))/;

Comment: thank you for your comment! ... its not so much as I intended, but good approach :)

Comment: Happy to help. 